# Golang transform http.Header into array

Tags: go

I'm sending POST request:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", link, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
client := &http.Client{Timeout: tm}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

I receive `resp.Header` in format with type `http.Header`

I need to something like this:

```
[
    "Server: nginx/1.4.4",
    "Date: Wed, 24 Feb 2016 19:09:49 GMT"
]
```

I don't know how to approach this problem, because I don't know how to deal with `http.Header` datatype. Could someone help please

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header

Answer (score 9):

`resp.Header` is of type [`http.Header`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header). You can see in the documentation that this type is also a `map`, so you can access it in two different ways:

1) By using `http.Header`'s methods:

```
serverValue := resp.Header().Get("Server")
dataValue := resp.Header().Get("Date")
```

If the header exists, you'll get its first value (keep in mind that there might be multiple values for a single header name); otherwise you'll get an empty string.

2) By using `map`'s methods:

```
serverValue, ok := resp.Header()["Server"]
dataValue, ok := resp.Header()["Date"]
```

If the header exists, `ok` will be `true` (i.e. the header *exists*) and you'll get a slice of strings containing all the values for that header; otherwise, `ok` will be `false` (i.e. the header *doesn't exist*).

Use whichever method you prefer.

If you need to iterate over all the header values, you can do it with something like:

```
for name, value := range resp.Header() {
    fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, value)
}
```

Comment: `resp.Header()[..]` is not going to work. Header is a non-function, what you're looking for is `resp.Header.Get("whatever")`

Answer (score 8):

You could use a function like this one:

```
func HeaderToArray(header http.Header) (res []string) {
    for name, values := range header {
        for _, value := range values {
            res = append(res, fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s", name, value))
        }
    }
    return
}
```

It should return an array like the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

## This solutions is for `go version go1.13 windows/amd64`.

The request object from `http.Request` contains `Header` object. We are using `net/http` package here. You can get values of all headers by name using following method:

```
import(
    "net/http"
)

type RequestHeaders struct {
    ContentType      string      `json: "content-type"`
    Authorization    string      `json: "authorization"`
}

func getHeaders(r *http.Request) RequestHeaders {
        contentType := r.Header.Get("Content-Type")
        authorization := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
        headers := RequestHeaders{
                        Content-Type: contentType,
                        Authorization: authorization}
        return headers
}
```

You can see that we are using `r.Header.Get("Content-Type")` method to get value of the header.

*If the header is missing the `Get()` method will return empty string.*

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the response header's first value with `resp.Header().Get()`, which returns `""` if the header key has no values.

Hence, in your case

```
var a [2]string
a[0] = resp.Header().Get("server")
a[1] = resp.Header().Get("date")
```